# Функция по поиску значений в словаре

Tags: python, dict

Не могу разобраться с тем, как выводить информацию из словаря. В данном случае нужно вводить название города, а затем написать, кто в нём живёт, но работает всё время с ошибками.

```
def is_anyone_in(collection, city):
    if city in collection:  # если есть среди значений словаря collection 
        for name in collection.values(): # переберите все ключи словаря
            if name == city:  # если соответствующее ключу значение равно city
                print('В городе ' + city + ' живёт ' + name + '.')
    else:
        print('Пока никого.')

friends = {
    'Серёга': 'Омск', 
    'Соня': 'Москва', 
    'Дима': 'Челябинск', 
    'Алина': 'Хабаровск', 
    'Егор': 'Пермь'
}

is_anyone_in(friends, 'Хабаровск')
```

Answer (score 2):

`if city in collection:` проверяет наличие `city` среди ключей, а не значений. В `name` находится город а не имя, вам надо итерировать сразу и по ключам и по значения

также лучше использовать `f` строки

```
def is_anyone_in(collection, city):
    if city in collection.values():  # если есть среди значений словаря collection 
        for name, city1 in collection.items(): # переберите все ключи словаря
            if city1 == city:  # если соответствующее ключу значение равно city
                print(f'В городе {city} живёт {name}.')
    else:
        print('Пока никого.')
```

Answer (score 1):

у вам список наизнанку просто, с ним можно так:

```
friends = {
    'Серёга': 'Омск',
    'Соня': 'Москва',
    'Дима': 'Челябинск',
    'Алина': 'Хабаровск',
    'Егор': 'Пермь'
}

city = 'Хабаровск'

res = [name for name in friends if friends[name] == city]

print("в Хабаровск:",  "никто не живет." if res == [] else ', '.join(res))
```